# Configuration block in a Gem

Tags: ruby, rubygems

I'm having a go at writing my first gem, but am a bit confused as to how the typical configuration blocks work. To illustrate, what I want to have is the facility to write something like

```
MyGem.configure do |c|
    c.property1 = 1
    c.property2 = 'some string'
end
```

My ruby knowledge is less than deep, so while I'm happy using blocks, I'm not sure how to write code that *expects* a block.

How do I write my "MyGem" class to be configured (presumably via an instance variable) in this way?

Comment: http://www.tweetegy.com/2012/01/ruby-blocks-procs-and-lambdas/

Answer (score 5):

This would be the likely way to implement your example:

```
class MyGem
  Config = Struct.new :property1, :property2  # => MyGem::Config

  def self.configure(&config_block)
    config_block.call config         # => "some string"
  end                                # => :configure

  def self.config
    @config ||= Config.new  # => #<struct MyGem::Config property1=nil, property2=nil>, #<struct MyGem::Config property1=1, property2="some string">
  end                       # => :config
end                         # => :config

MyGem.configure do |c|         # => MyGem
  c.property1 = 1              # => 1
  c.property2 = 'some string'  # => "some string"
end                            # => "some string"

MyGem.config  # => #<struct MyGem::Config property1=1, property2="some string">
```

But I'll also advocate storing state on the instance rather than the class:

```
class MyGem
  Config = Struct.new :property1, :property2  # => MyGem::Config
  def initialize(&config_block)
    config_block.call config                  # => "some string"
  end                                         # => :initialize

  def config
    @config ||= Config.new  # => #<struct MyGem::Config property1=nil, property2=nil>, #<struct MyGem::Config property1=1, property2="some string">
  end                       # => :config
end                         # => :config

instance = MyGem.new do |c|    # => MyGem
  c.property1 = 1              # => 1
  c.property2 = 'some string'  # => "some string"
end                            # => #<MyGem:0x007fc1691ecb20 @config=#<struct MyGem::Config property1=1, property2="some string">>

instance.config  # => #<struct MyGem::Config property1=1, property2="some string">
```

If you do it this way, you don't have global state. Notice we could have multiple different configurations (e.g. each client has their own config, or you want to write more than one test, but now each one risks breaking the others). I wrote a blog about many ways I'd thought of to implement the singleton pattern, and why you shouldn't do it: http://blog.8thlight.com/josh-cheek/2012/10/20/implementing-and-testing-the-singleton-pattern-in-ruby.html

Comment: It's normally better to `yield(config) if block_given?` than to capture the block and make a messy `call` to it. That's largely a stylistic concern, but there can be performance considerations for capturing blocks.

Comment: I disagree: it's ultimately irrelevant what you do. Yielding is a little faster, but that rarely ever matters, especially for a configuration block. Explicitly taking and naming the variable is clearer (you can see the block in the signature, and the name can convey what its for), and is ultimately more powerful, because it can pass the block to another method. To get that with yield, you must resort to the incredibly hacky `def mymeth() yourmeth &Proc.new end`

Comment: In the case of passing the capture method is obviously cleaner, not denying that. Does depend on the circumstances. Great answer though.

Comment: And by "rarely ever matters" I mean that it matters so little that worrying about such things is a literal waste of your time, b/c unless you find a way to scale it like placing it in a loop at the bottom of a common callchain, its on the scale of pennies in Fort Knox.

Comment: I'm just giving an alternative here, something that's used by convention and people need to be familiar with. The `yield` approach performs over 4x faster even in Ruby 2.1.5 [according to a simple benchmark](https://gist.github.com/tadman/ca6aa45faf7c16c04075), so you have performance sensitive code, every bit helps. Otherwise, clarity may be a priority as you suggest.

Comment: A single call to a database, an HTTP request, a file read, a suboptimal algorithm in a critical section of code, these things will have a noticeable effect. Accessing the block via macros or objects will not. If speed is so critical that you're cluttering your brain with this, then you need to drop to a lower layer of abstraction than Ruby (e.g. C in MRI).